# What algorithm can be used here

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This is an interview question, not a homework.

N friends are playing a game. Each of them has a list of numbers in front of himself.

Each of N friends chooses a number from his list and reports it to the game administrator. Then the game administrator sorts the reported numbers and shouts the K-th largest number.

I must the count all possible numbers that the game administrator can shout.

For example, if N = 3 and K = 3, and the lists for the 3 friends are `2 5 3`, `8 1 6`, `7 4 9`. The output is 6, since the possible values are `4 5 6 7 8 9`.

Can anybody suggest a decent algorithm for this problem? What I am doing is to create all possible permutations taking one number from each list, then sorting the resultant and printing the kth-largest. But that takes too much time.

Comment: Why can't 1, 2 or 3 be chosen by the players, and be the 3rd largest number? Similarly, how can 7, 8 or 9 be third largest number from the set?

Comment: From what i understood, the N-th greastest number is the greatest number. That's not the usual way to name it, but i'm not sure there is a convention for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To know if a number is present in the result or not, you need to know for each other list if there are numbers above and if there are numbers below. List where there are both numbers above and below are not a problem as you can choose a number in them as it suits you. The problem are lists where there are only numbers above or only numbers below. The first ones must be at most N-K, the second ones must be at most K. If this is not true, your number cannot be picked. If this is true, you can always choose numbers in the lists where there are both number above and below so that your number is picked.

This can be checked in linear time, or even better if your first sort your lists, thus giving an overall complexity of O(n.log(n)) where n is the number of numbers in total. Without sorting you got a n² complexity.

In your example with lists :

```
{2 5 3}, {8 1 6}, {7 4 9}
```

say we are looking for the 2-greatest number. For each number we ask if it can be shout by the administator. For each of them we look if in the other list there are both numbers below and numbers above. Let's look further for some of them

- For 5 : there is numbers above and below in both other lists. So "5" can be shout by the administrator.
- For "2" : there is numbers above and below in the second list so I can freely choose a number above or below in this list. But there are only numbers above in the third list, so the picked number in this list will always be greater. Since i can freely choose a number below in the second list, thus making my "2" the 2nd greatest number.
- For "1" : there is only numbers above in the second list, so "1" will always be the smallest element.
- For "9" : this is the other way round, it is always the greatest.

Comment: Please explain in a bit more detail!

Comment: Do you mean to say that in case there is a list here there are only numbers above this number, there can be at most `n-k` number of such lists?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If there are more than N-K such lists, then in each reported set of numbers, there are more than N-K numbers greater. Thus, your number can't be the K-greatest.

Comment: So how can we get `Nlog N` here? We have to take two nested loops, one for the current element from each list, and the other to count the number of other lists where the number falls midway or at extreme ends. So a nested loop, plus the check whther element lies in midway or extreme, that's `N^2 log N`, right?

Comment: But in order to be the kth greatest number, at most k-1 elements can be greater, why n-k?

Comment: This is not the same N. As I wrote, my n (small n) is the number of numbers in total. That is N x M, where M is the number of numbers in each list.

Comment: This is not the definition of K-greatest element you used in your example. Just swap N and N-K and add/substract 1 if needed.

Comment: Yeah, so for each number in each list (N in total), I have to check where the number lies in each of the other lists (I can avoid binary search for all by presorting all of them and checking only the first and last elements). So presorting N lists take NlogN, plus the nested loop takes N^3. Can't it be bettered?

Comment: Sorting cost N.log(N), so you actually have N².log(N). You might want to consider the solution from maniek, which requires more proof but can be more efficient.

Comment: Now that I think about it. The solutions are almost the same... instead of sorting the lists, just compute their maximum and minimum. So you just have to compare your current number with those values. Then it can be improved a bit by proving (needs a bit more work) that each element above the K-est minimum and below the (N-K)-est maximum is always in the result. You get Maniek solution, N² complexity.

Comment: Can't it be bettered than `O(N^2)`?

Comment: Of course not. You need O(N²) operations to read the whole set of N² numbers. If you don't read one of the numbers, you result can be false.

Comment: So essentially, the algorith consists of two parts. First, iterating over all the lists, where in each list, by running the first pass of a bubble sort twice, I find the smallest and largest number. Keeping this in an array, I proceed to the next list. At the end, sort both lists to find kth smallest from one and (n-k)th largest from another. Now again iterating over each item in each list, check whether that item lies in between these to numbers, right?

Comment: Right, except that you can do simpler than a bubble sort first pass to get their maximum and minimum.

Comment: What I wrote about minimum complexity isn't true. Sometimes, you can avoid reading some numbers in the list, if you know that its minimum and maximum is already the minimum and maximum of all elements. But that won't change the minimal complexity of N².

Comment: When you say (n-k)th maximum, if the largest number from each list is stored in an array, and then sorted in increasing order, it will be `array[-(n-k)]`, right?

Comment: Depends on the language (0- or 1-indexed arrays ?) and of the interpretation of your problem. Though, i don't know why you are using a - before (n-k).

Comment: Strictly you dont need to sort the sets, only to find the largest and smallest element in every set. That is linear, and knowing the largest and smallest element tells you immedately if all elements are smaller or larger, so its all linear time in the number of elements (rather than the number of sets).

Comment: This is what I said above.

Answer (score 6):

take the smallest number from each set. find the K-th -largest of these. This is the smallest number that is in the result. Similarly, find the largest number in the result. Prove that Each number between the two is in the result.

Comment: How to find the largest number in the result? Please explain in a bit more detail!

Comment: As he said similarly. Think a bit.