# Explain example of giving K-th largest number of numbers from each of N given sets?

Tags: facebook, algorithm

Today I tried to solve a [Facebook Programming Challenge](https://facebook.interviewstreet.com/recruit/challenges/). The challenge that I got was the 'Bar problem', which can be found [here](https://github.com/alonsovidales/facebook-programming-challenges/tree/master/bar). My problem during the course of the challenge was to understand the first example that they provided.

The problem can be summarized as follows:

> N friends are playing a game. Each of them has a list of numbers in front of himself.
>
> Each of N friends chooses a number from his list and reports it to the game administrator. Then the game administrator sorts the reported numbers and shouts the K-th largest number.
>
> You want to know the count all possible numbers that the game administrator can shout.

To that point I thought that I had understood the problem but then they presented the following example:

> In the sample example given, for the first testcase N = 3 and K = 3. List for the first person is {2 5 3}, {8 1 6} for second and {7 4 9} for the third. In this case all the numbers in {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} have a chance to be the third biggest selected number.

So my question is:

**How can 7, 8 and 9 be the third biggest selected number?**

In my opinion only the numbers {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} can be third biggest number but maybe I misunderstood the algorithm.

Comment: They can't, of course. It's not clear what the question author actually meant.

Comment: If anybody is interested, they never responded to my feedback in which I reported the problem to them. It would be nice if others who have taken the test could tell whether the question has been revised.

Comment: I took it recently. It remains the same because you didn't understand the author's intent. By 3rd largest number (K = 3) with 3 contestants (N = 3), 3rd largest means the **largest number of all of the submissions,** which satisfies the test case. Perhaps you're thinking of the 3rd *from largest.* The phrasing obviously isn't the best.

Comment: I appreciate your comment very much, though I don't understand how "3rd largest means the largest number of all of the submissions" rather than "3rd from largest". When I google "third largest" I am confronted with a whole lot of cases that support my thinking (3rd from largest). Additionally a lot of people participating in this question also seem to have thought my way, which in my opinion should worry the person who created the problem.

Comment: You know, I'm thinking the fact that you discovered the inconsistency between the problem and the example could actually be the right solution to the challenge. If the challenge is to realize that the problem is formulated incorrectly, then that's exactly what you did.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What algorithm can be used here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669102/what-algorithm-can-be-used-here)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are right, they sorted the numbers the wrong way. The proposed example reply looks like the correct reply if you want to get the third smallest, not the third greatest. That is, sorting them from smallest to greatest, you get the third. This is not what stated in the question (but English is not my first language so I may get it wrong).

Answer (score 0):

The question must mean third smallest.

Given an array of sets, S_1,S_2...S_N, select one, and select a given element. Presume that we know both the largest and smallest element in every set, and divde the sets into three groups. Those in which all elements are greater than e, those in which all elements are less than e, and those in which there are elements both greater than and less than e.

For a set of N sets, and the k smallest, there must be no more than k-1 sets with all elements smaller than e, and no more than N-k sets with all elements greater than e. If those two conditions hold, i can take those sets which are both larger and smaller than e and arrange them in such a way that e would be chosen.