# Efficient algorithm to find kth largest numbers from N lists by picking one number each time from N lists

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, language-agnostic, permutation

There are given N lists of numbers. Every time one number will be picked from each list and all the picked numbers will be sorted. The k th largest of sorted numbers will be added to a set.
Finally the size of the set will be reported.

For Example

3 3

3 2 5 3

3 8 1 6

3 7 4 9

First integer is the no of lists N(From next line there are N lists. In this case it is 3, so next three lines have list values). Second integer is the k value.And first entry of the next N lines are the list size.

List values are list1 -> (2,5,3) , list2 ->(8,1,6), list3 ->(7,4,9)

Any number can be picked from the list. For example (2,8,7),(2,8,4),(2,8,9),(2,1,7),(2,1,4),(2,1,9)..etc are all valid combinations. From this combinations kth largest will be selected from each combination.

In this case the following numbers have the chance to be the 3 rd largest (since k=3)

(4,5,6,7,8,9)

The total count must be reported. So the output is 6

**One way:**

I am trying to find the permutation of all the list values, sort it and take the k th largest every time. In this way the complexity is high. For example 4 lists of sizes (10,12,15,20)= (10 *12 * 15 * 20) list values. So it will not fit in memory.

Is there any other efficient algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Can you provide an example for the problem? Description seems vague.

Comment: @st0le - I added an example for the problem.

Comment: How come that 5 is in the final list, but not 3? When you read the first list you do not know what will come later, right? Or are the numbers "picked" in random order? You must be more specific how your final set is composed.

Comment: @corpoc - Yes. Any number can be the part of the combination. I added some valid combinations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explain example of giving K-th largest number of numbers from each of N given sets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17927746/explain-example-of-giving-k-th-largest-number-of-numbers-from-each-of-n-given-se)

Comment: I really do not understand this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question , took a while to figure it out .
Make 2 max-heaps , `h1` and `h2` .

put 1st element of all lists at each time in `h1` , and 1 element (maximum) from `h1` to `h2` and when size of `h2 >=K` ,
pop 1 element (maximum) from `h2` and add it into your `set` .

Run on your case :

1) `h1` = empty         `h2` = empty   `set`=empty
2) `h1` = 2 8 7         `h2` = empty   `set`=empty
3) `h1` = 2 7 5 1 4     `h2` = 8       `set`=empty
4) `h1` = 2 5 1 4 3 6 9 `h2` = 8 7     `set`=empty
5) `h1` = 2 5 1 4 3 6   `h2` = 8 7 9   `set`=empty
6) `h1` = 2 5 1 4 3     `h2` = 8 7 6   `set`=9
7) `h1` = 2 1 4 3     `h2` = 5 7 6   `set`=9 8
8) `h1` = 2 1 3       `h2` = 5 4 6   `set`=9 8 7
9) `h1` = 2 1         `h2` = 5 4 3   `set`=9 8 7 6
10) `h1` = 1          `h2` = 2 4 3   `set`=9 8 7 6 5
11) `h1` = empty      `h2` = 2 1 3   `set`=9 8 7 6 5 4

`h1` = empty , STOP.

Time complexity : `O(N log N)`

Comment: It is a very good try. The lists can be of any size.In the example fortunately all the lists have the same size.And the combination can be any number from the list. So when we take a particular combination , for example (3,8,4) the kth largest is 8(since k=3). But based on your logic it will take some other number since 8 is already added.That should not be case. So your logic will fail for other large inputs.

Comment: @DineshAppavoo: by ` since 8 is already added` do you mean duplicates can be there ? If so , make a hash table , and don't ass the repeated element again . and if the lists are not of same size , that will not matter much , as when end of a list has reached , just don't consider that list again .

Comment: The logic what you have given is taking 0th index element of all lists, then 1st index elements of all lists , then 2nd index elements of all lists like that. But in the description it says any number from the list. For example (2,8,7),(2,8,4),(2,8,9),(2,1,7),(2,1,4),(2,1,9)..etc are all valid combinations. From this combinations kth largest will be selected from each combination. So the logic should be for all permutation of N list values the kth largest must be reported. If you run your code for the logic it will give output list as (total list values - first k entries).

Comment: @DineshAppavoo: Then above algorithm will work perfectly when lists are sorted in descending order otherwise or when k>=number of lists .  
I assumed that you want to pick first unseen element from each list by mistake .
So, i think it's not possible to do in O(NlogN) time and if you get a good algorithm , do share !

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will share for sure:).